# Jump to anchor Typescript on Child Route

Tags: angular, typescript, anchor-scroll

My project is broken into 4 modules and each module has its own child routes. The requirement is one template of my Angular project requires a jump to anchor. To access the page it routes through the module router and the @NgModule is .forChild.

I have included the ExtraOptions in the .forRoot router. However, when I click on the link for the jump to it only reloads the page. I have also set the onSameUrlNavigation to ignore.

Is it possible to use ExtraOptions on a child route? When I tried originally to add the ExtraOptions to the child route it gave me the error that it was looking for 1 argument, but received 2. Shouldn't the jump to work even if it is set in the root router?

Thank you for any clarification. I am not able to include any code due to the sensitivity of the code, my apologies in advance.

Comment: Have you also added `anchorScrolling: 'enabled'` to `ExtraOptions` in `forRoot()` ?

Comment: Yes I currently have anchorScrolling enabled in the forRoot()

Comment: In my ExtraOptions this is what I have:
const routerOptions: ExtraOptions = {
  scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',
  anchorScrolling: 'enabled',
  scrollOffset: [0, 10],
  onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload',
  useHash: true
};

Answer (score 0):

After creating an example project I discovered that the issue isn't with the anchor scroll, but something deeper with how the project has been built. I am closing this issue. Thank you!